# How much force is each leg supporting?

Tags: forces, torque, equilibrium

Assuming that the plank rotate in the red dot and it weights 10kg, how can we calculate the weight or force each leg is supporting?

I tried the following system, assuming the left most leg is supporting F1 and the second is supporting F2, also gravity is 9.8:

- 5F1 + 3F2 = 9.8 * 10
- F1 + F2 = 9.8 * 10

I tried to use the torque equation T = F * r
I got the solution F1 = -980N and F2 = 1960 but the solution don't make sense because I have a negative value.

What I did wrong, how I can calculate correctly this?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: There are 3 legs, not just 2. You forgot one force.

Comment: Oh I fought that the right leg didn't count because I saw this as a torque problem but if that was the case then I should count the leg to the system and all should be good?

Comment: I don't think that you can find the forces from just equilibrium conditions for forces and torques. It looks like it is undetermined.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my mind is boggling, It's confusing how the weight distributes over points, if you do this experiment in real life I'm sure that the outcome shall be the same, what I'm missing here? It's not suppose to have like a predictable way to know how the weight will spread over the points?

Comment: Considering the beam deformable (more realistic) rather than rigid may give a solution. But not so simple.

Comment: I'm not aware of that, do you have something that I can look up, read or something?

Comment: You could try to look up stress distribution in supported beams or similar. It is a standard problem for engineering students. But you need all the details about materials of the beam and supports as well as their geometry and dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think to have a valuable answer for my problem I need to learn and investigate more.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make some simplifying assumptions to get an easy answer.

For example, if you assume the rightmost support and the plank are rigid, then it follows that the leftmost support compresses 5/3x as much as the middle support.  Using this information, I think you will be able to solve for the force at each support if you know the stiffness of each support using simple static force and moment balance equations.

Good luck.

**EDIT Based on Comments:**

Ok, so you have 3 unknowns: $F_1$, $F_2$, and $F_3$.  So you need 3 equations to solve for these unknowns.

$F_1 = 5/3 \cdot F_2$

$F_1 + F_2 + F_3 = mg$

and sum the moments about the left support to get:

$2 F_2 + 5 F_3 = 5 \cdot 2/3 \cdot mg$

(My memory is that the moment created by the weight of the plank is equal to 2/3 the length of the plank times the weight.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't make the question clear but yes, the rightmost support and the plank are rigid. But the equation I did is not the same thing? 5F1 + 3F2 = 9.8 * 10?
I'm using the torque equation (T = F*r) and the equilibrium of forces where 5F1 + 3F2 - 9.8*10 = 0. I did miss something?

Comment: I don't know how to apply the stiffness, but if I assume it's the same is worth using it?

Comment: @DavidSousa:  See the additions to my answer above.